# pre-rendering nextjs getStaticProps() giving an Error: Image is missing required "src" with next/image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

From reading the nextjs documentation the getStaticProps should pre-render data that I want before a user comes to my site. I am trying to get images before I load them onto cards.

Here in my **index.js**

```
 export async function getStaticProps() {
    const images = getImages();
    return {
        props: {
            data: await Promise.all(images), // wait for all images to load
        }, revalidate: 5
    };
}
```

The **getImages** function looks like this

```
export function getImages() {
    const frameCount = 39;
    const data = [];
    for (let id = 0; id <= frameCount; id++) {
        // add new promise to array
        data.push(
            fetch(`http://localhost:3000/GeneratedImgs/${id}.png`).then(
                (res) => res.url
            )
        );
    }
    return data;
}
```

So then in the **index.js** I pass that data into a component which passes it into another component to the next/image.

```
export default function Home({ data }) {
    
    let testCardGrid = <div className="loading"></div>;
    if (data !== null) {
        mouseCardGrid = <CardGrid data={data} />;
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Mouse</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>

            <Header />
            {testCardGrid}
            <Map />
        </>
    );
}
```

**CardGrid.js** looks like this:

```
export default function CardGrid({ data }) {
    let cardArray = [];
    let randomNumbers = [];

    function getRandomInts(quantity, max) {
        const arr = [];
        while (arr.length < quantity) {
            var candidateInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
            if (arr.indexOf(candidateInt) === -1) arr.push(candidateInt);
        }
        return arr;
    }

    randomNumbers = getRandomInts(8, 40);
    randomNumbers.forEach((num) => {
        cardArray.push({
            title: `Card#${num}`,
            imageUrl: data[num]
        });
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("cardgrid triggered");
    }, []);
    return (
        <section id="content" className="section-padding">
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    {cardArray.map((object) => (
                        <Card title={object.title} imageUrl={object.imageUrl} />
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}
```

Finally the **Card.js** file looks like this:

```
export default function Card({ title, imageUrl }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("card added");
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
            <div className="card text-center">
                <Image
                    priority
                    className="card-img-top"
                    src={imageUrl}
                    height={300}
                    width={300}
                />

                <div className="card-body">
                    <h2 className="card-text">{title}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

After I refresh the page a couple of times or when I go to a differnt page on the site and come back to the home page it will give me the error:

**Unhandled Runtime Error**
Error: Image is missing required "src" property. Make sure you pass "src" in props to the `next/image` component. Received: {"width":300,"height":300}

I was trying to show a loading div if the data was null and thought I could try the revalidate attribute the getStaticProps() method has but it too was giving me the same error.

So, I am not sure I understand this because I thought that the getStaticProps would always get the images before the page loads. I see in the docs that it says it runs under next build. So is it just once and done? Am I missing a fundamental concept of pre-rendering? please give me your advice.

Comment: Can you explain to me the use of getRandomInts?

Comment: It gets an array of unique numbers of size 8 from a range of 0 to 40.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next.js Image component error src missing though I am providing the src prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68524500/next-js-image-component-error-src-missing-though-i-am-providing-the-src-prop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these this correction shoukd be done in `getImages`:

```
export function getImages() {
  const frameCount = 39;
  const data = [];
  for (let id = 0; id <= frameCount; id++) {
     // change this to

     data.push(`http://localhost:3000/GeneratedImgs/${id}.png`);
  }
  return data;
}
```

Also, when trying to test `getRandomInts` one of the results was `40` which will be `undefined`, so maybe you should change it to the below:

```
// remove + 1
// It's also recommended to use `let` instead of `var`
let candidateInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
```

Comment: Yep it was the 40 that was causing the error! Damn, thank you!

Comment: @kpgabriel you're welcome and glad to help!