# how to make next.js load images from public source with default img element

Tags: next.js

I have an SVG image I want to render through the classic JSX Element `<img>`, in place of the `<Image>`.

```
    <img
      src="/public/smiley-face.svg"
      css={classes.sideSmileyFace}
      alt="Presentation logo"
      role="presentation"
    />
```

This way, the IDE does not complain about the position of my SVG file, but it's not rendered: the compilation does not transform that path into the correct one. On the other hand, if I place `src="smiley-face.svg` it does work, but the IDE complains. Any idea to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next.js Image component error src missing though I am providing the src prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68524500/next-js-image-component-error-src-missing-though-i-am-providing-the-src-prop)

Comment: _"it does work, but the IDE complains"_ - what is the IDE complaining about?

Answer (score 1):

Files in the local `public` directory end up being served from "root" (`https://whatever/`) after compilation.

For regular `<img />`, either `src="smiley-face.svg"` or `src="/smiley-face.svg"` will work, with or without the leading slash (but don't include the word "public").

Next's custom `<Image />` component on the other hand requires a leading slash since your image is relative (i.e., inside `public`). So only `src="/smiley-face.svg"` will work.

As for your IDE complaining, I'm guessing you're talking about a message that looks something like this?

> Do not use `<img>`. Use Image from 'next/image' instead.

If so, you can turn that message off by setting that rule to "off" in your `.eslintrc.json` file:

```js
{
  "extends": ["next/core-web-vitals"], // or whatever existing settings you have
  "rules": {
    "@next/next/no-img-element": "off" // add this
  }
}
```